# Ramda propOr type error in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

This is a simple question, I just cannot find out how to resolve type Typescript typing issue while using Ramda.

My code

```
const podName = R.propOr(null, 'podName', node) as String | null
```

error:

```
TS2352:Type 'propOr_general_011' cannot be converted to type 'String'. Property 'charAt' is missing in type 'propOr_general_011'
```

Any idea why above error is occuring? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TypeScript needs to be convinced that the node.podName value is either a String, null, or absent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look at the help section on how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  This answer as it stands is fairly basic and might get flagged as "low quality"

Answer (score 0):

There's a TypeScript "types" package on npm that should address this for you. Among other libraries, it has [types for Ramda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ramda): just add it to your package.json file with `npm install --save-dev @types/ramds` or `yarn add -D @types/ramda`. It resolved a bunch of those errors for me.